# Flask Admin - performance difficulties

Tags: performance, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am facing to performance problem in Flask-Admin, although performance of Flask application is good.

my model is:

```
class Ck(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ck"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    nazev = Column(String(100))
    kontakt = Column(Text)
    terms = relationship(Term, backref=backref('ck', lazy='noload'), lazy='dynamic')


class Term(Base):
    __tablename__ = "term"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    hotel_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hotel.id'))
    ck_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ck.id'))
    ...
    addons = relationship(Addon, secondary=term_addon, backref=backref('term', lazy='noload'), lazy='dynamic')


class Hotel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "hotel"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    country_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('country.id'))
    area_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('area.id'))
    ...
    photos = relationship(Photo, backref=backref('hotel', lazy='select'), lazy='dynamic')
    terms = relationship(Term, backref=backref('hotel', lazy='noload'), lazy='dynamic')


class Addon(Base):
    __tablename__ = "addon"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ...
```

There are really lot of records in terms and much more in addons. If I click to anywhere to get details of Hotel, Term, Ck or Addon in Flask-Admin, it is not possible, because it doesn't finish till timeout.

Please could you advise me where I can improve it?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Enable AJAX foreign key loading. See here: http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask.ext.admin.model.BaseModelView.form_ajax_refs