# Long loading data in flask-admin relationship dropdown input

Tags: flask, flask-admin

How to reduce the amount of data in the related table when editing and inserting item form in Flask-admin.

In my related tables more than 500,000 records ...
And the flask-admin uploads all the data in the associated drop-down input (example `film`).... and can not do it.

I created my model mysql innodb through SQLAlchemy.

I can load the data in the parts table? or disable the loading of related data

```
class LfMailerQueue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'lf_mailer_queue'

    mail_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    template_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(u'lf_mailer.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(u'modx_user_attributes.internalKey'), index=True)
    film_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(u'modx_lfvideo_items.id'), index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255))
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue())

    film = db.relationship(u'ModxLfvideoItem', primaryjoin='LfMailerQueue.film_id == ModxLfvideoItem.id', backref=u'lf_mailer_queues')
    template = db.relationship(u'LfMailer', primaryjoin='LfMailerQueue.template_id == LfMailer.id', backref=u'lf_mailer_queues')
    user = db.relationship(u'ModxUserAttribute', primaryjoin='LfMailerQueue.user_id == ModxUserAttribute.internalKey', backref=u'lf_mailer_queues')


class ModxLfvideoItem(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'modx_lfvideo_items'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.group
    ....


class ModxUserAttribute(db.Model): 

....
```

Comment: Use [Ajax loading](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/?highlight=Ajax#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_ajax_refs)

Comment: thank, great... i will try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask Admin - performance difficulties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894861/flask-admin-performance-difficulties)